# MediaElement JS is not styling my audio tag if it is inside the for each loop in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

Hi I am using Knockout JS and MediaElement JS together.

MediaElement JS is just a plugin to style/customize my audio player (HTML5).

Here's my audio snippet inside the `foreach` loop:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: tracks">
    <tr class="search-track" data-bind="attr: { id: 'search-track-' + $index() + '' }">
       <td class="search-title-col" data-bind="attr: { id: 'search-col-' + $index() + '' }">

         <div class="audio-player">
        <h2>The Good Lawdz - Evidence Song</h2>
        <audio id="audio-player" src="media/evidence-song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
         </div><!-- @end .audio-player -->

        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

And here is my JS located in html file, inside the body tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
            alwaysShowControls: true,
            features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
            audioVolume: 'horizontal',
            audioWidth: 450,
            audioHeight: 70,
            iPadUseNativeControls: true,
            iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
            AndroidUseNativeControls: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I badly want to use my custom style(s).

I followed this tutorial in styling audio player: http://designshack.net/articles/css/custom-html5-audio-element-ui/

Basically, I tried to put the audio player outside the `for each` and it styled just fine. How come that it is not working when it is inside the looping?

I'm new to Knockout JS so please bear with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are you are seeing this because when you are executing the `.mediaelementplayer()` function before Knockout has added the audio players into the DOM, so there is nothing to style.

You could defer evaluation if you wanted, but you may still run into a timing issue.  Try using a custom binding handler here -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.bindingHandlers.audioPlayer = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).mediaelementplayer({
            alwaysShowControls: true,
            features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
            audioVolume: 'horizontal',
            audioWidth: 450,
            audioHeight: 70,
            iPadUseNativeControls: true,
            iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
            AndroidUseNativeControls: true
        });
    };
</script>
```

Which you could use in your HTML something like this -

```
<audio data-bind="audioPlayer: {}" id="audio-player" src="media/evidence-song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

One note is that you are setting the Id inside the foreach which means multiple elements will have the exact same Id - generally a bad practice.